# C3P0 calls Han Solo "Captain Turner"

Tags: star-wars

In [Star Wars Episode V: The Empire Strikes Back](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_Wars_Episode_V%3a_The_Empire_Strikes_Back), when they get back to the Millennium Falcon after escaping from Hoth, C-3PO calls Han "Captain Turner" twice during the panic when they escape into an asteroid field.

Why does he use this name?

Comment: I'm guessing C3PO said "Captain, turn her" and you misinterpreted.

Comment: You may want to post some links to these instances.  That or quote it from text somewhere and link the reference.  Then I will reverse my -1.

Comment: Turner? He barely knew 'er.

Comment: "during the panic when they escape into an asteroid field." This event does not occur in the series. Do you mean after they escape from Hoth and before they land in the big asteroid with the [space slug](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Exogorth)?

Comment: You're right, DampeS8N and DigsyMadrox.  I think it is in Episode V after they leave Hoth.

Comment: Didn't find any occurrence in the script (http://www.blueharvest.net/scoops/esb-script.shtml). Don't know if it's based on the real one. Entering in the asteroids field is around the 52nd occurence of "THREEPIO"

Comment: I do not see it actually in the script and the script mentions nothing about threepio giving any flying instructions to Han.  Leia and Threepio say "Closer!?" but no captian before it.

Comment: Han says "turn her" twice when they are in the asteroid field. No one else says "turn her" in the ESB script according to http://www.blueharvest.net/scoops/esb-script.shtml

Comment: Is [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uTp8mKFxmbg) scene the one you're talking about?  Because I don't hear any instance of "Captain Turner" nor "Captain, turn her"...

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I believe this is in Episode V, "Empire Strikes Back," and if so I remember the instances you are talking about (watched "ESB" way too much...or not enough). I've always thought it was just his English accent. The original "Star Wars" trilogy is full of rushed and unclear dialogue (I thought Han Solo was saying "Boat attack" instead of "Boba Fett" in "ROTJ" for years) and dual pronunciations (Leia/Lee-a).

Comment: I think the distortion/muffling from the mask may have also contributed.

Comment: I found it. It's at about 10:10 [in this clip](http://youtu.be/WASr5-mS238). It's right before the Falcon has managed to start up and take off. And you are right - it's just C3PO's robotic British voice, but when I first heard it, I did hear "Captain Turner", but it really is "Captain Solo", just as you say here, Brett.

Comment: It's like [Laurel and Yanny](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yanny_or_Laurel), or [Harbulary batteries](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/173898/why-does-drax-call-them-harbulary-batteries).

Answer (score 0):

If you turn on your CC you'll see C3PO is in fact saying "Captain Solo". I thought he was saying "Turner" also, that's why I googled it. Once you watch it with CC on you'll hear it correctly.