# Why does Drax call them Harbulary batteries?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, guardians-of-the-galaxy-2

In Guardians of the Galaxy 2, Rocket steals some shiny batteries called Anulax batteries.

[image]

But Drax insists they are called Harbulary batteries. The pronunciation isn't even close.

> Drax: What are they called again?
>
> Peter: Anulax batteries.
>
> Drax: Harbulary batteries.
>
> Peter: That's nothing like what I just said!

And later,

> Gamora: Peter, we almost died because of your arrogance.
>
> Peter: More like because he stole the Anulax batteries!
>
> Drax: They're called Harbulary batteries.
>
> Peter: No, they're not!

Why does Drax think they are called Harbulary batteries, and how is it that he gets the name so wrong yet so specific?

Comment: Just a nonsensical joke, Drax isn't paying attention and isn't the sharpest knife in the drawer.

Comment: @Petersaber, why would he has to pay for the attention? And why would you keep a knife that is not sharp in the drawer?

Comment: They aren't really as far apart as they seem at first.   Dropping/adding ***h***, producing/not producing the ***r*** (a la rhotic/non-rhotic dialects), substituting ***n*** / ***b***, keeping the ***ula***, and mangling the end of a word are all not too far fetched.    Far stranger changes has occurred in language (maybe not in the space of a few seconds, of course).

Comment: Looks like we have our own Drax in Edmund Dantes.

Comment: @sudhanva No. Drax is too big to be in Edmund Dantes.

Comment: May be a bit of "Fridge Brilliance". How does Peter (and the audience, by extension) perfectly understand all those alien beings, including Drax? Well, he supposedly uses a translation implant, as evidenced by his "mugshot" description in Kyln prison. What we may be seing is an example of something literally lost in translation - perhaps Drax makes only a slight error in pronunciation in his native language (or mixes two different but similarly sounding words), but translated it comes out sounding entirely different.

Answer (score 10):

The [junior novel](http://marvelcinematicuniverse.wikia.com/wiki/Guardians_of_the_Galaxy_Vol._2_(junior_novelization)) indicates that this is simply his *best attempt* to repeat what Peter is saying.

> *“Anulax batteries,” Quill answered.*
>
> *“Harbulary batteries,” **Drax repeated… sort of.***

Comment: If that was just his best attempt at pronouncing a word he doesn't know, why was he already *correcting* Peter the second time, so certain of the pronunciation?

Comment: @JDoe - Because he's not smart. He gets it wrong the first time, then convinces himself that he's right and Peter's wrong.

Comment: Bear in mind this is a Junior novel...

Comment: @Edlothiad - Indeed. And intended to be easy to understand, hence why they've explained a joke that shouldn't really need explaining to a native English speaker with a broad understanding of comic cinema

Answer (score -9):

Mu full theory: https://www.reddit.com/r/FanTheories/comments/7grs0l/infinity_war_the_most_logical_location_for_the/

TL;DR: Drax called them Harbulary batteries to hint that the Soul Stone's power is within the batteries. The Soul Stone is within the Hive in the Sovereign. Everything I have said is completely backed up with film evidence as well as support from comic book story lines.

Long story, short:
This involves much more than Drax being stupid, although 99% of fans will mark it off as that and forget about it. The real explanation behind Drax calling them "Harbulary" batteries is that the writers were slyly hinting that the batteries derive their power from the final Infinity Stone: the Soul Stone... Think about it. GotG2 starts off with the Guardians defeating a very powerful enemy from another dimension who is coming after the batteries. Why would a being from ANOTHER DIMNESION come to the Sovereign just for some batteries unless they were extremely powerful, and well-known throughout all dimensions. I am assuming only the Infinity Stones would be capable of attracting such a beast... High Priestess hired the Guardians because she knows that they can already handle a powerful enemy with an Infinity Stone (Ronan)

The Sovereign is a society that artificially births their inhabitants in a Hive looking thing. Their newest creation, Adam Warlock of course.... Now I know James Gunn has said Adam Warlock will not appear in Infinty War, but he never ruled out THE SOVEREIGN being in Infinity War. Adam could just easily still be in his cocoon when Thanos comes to steal the stone.

Also, is it not fishy that Rocket killed Ego with ease with a makeshift bomb he made using just TWO batteries??? In GotG1 he created a missile that could "blow up moons," and yet he hit Ronan with it point blank and Ronan didn't even get scratched. It would make sense for those batteries to contain the power of the SOUL STONE (destroying souls, capturing souls within the gem, absorbing souls, etc..)... Ego was one of THE OLDEST MOST OG celestial in the universe and yet his whole existence was ended with a makeshift bomb made by Rocket????????? I am not buying it unless those batteries possessed the power of the Soul Stone...This would also explain why Ayesha was so pissed at the Guardians for stealing the batteries.

Comment: Welcome to the site. I recommend you take our [tour] to see what kinds of answers we like to see here.

Comment: The last paragraph doesn't really follow. What does the moon-destroying missile have to do with your argument? Also, I would never assume that only the power from an infinity stone could attract an interdimensional being. That by itself requires a lot more assumptions that are just contradicted by the canon. Beings cross dimensions all the time for reasons that have nothing to do with infinity stones (or gems). I like theories like this though. I'll be thinking of it next time I watch GotG2.

Comment: This is officially incorrect as of *Infinity War*. The Soul Stone is not hidden in the batteries.